# Eager Load a Laravel relationship twice with different Scope filters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm working in Laravel 4.2.  I have three models of interest, Child, Family, and Addresses.  Family has a One-to-Many relationship with Child, and because the system tracks family mobility it also has a One-to-Many relationship with Address.  I'm trying to return two different addresses (technically two collections of addresses each expected to contain only one instance) for a single Child via eager loading, using two different scopes on Addresses to get both the original "qualifying" address for the school year as well as the child's final address.  As you can see in my code below, I've resorted to creating two different relationships between Family and Address ("qualifyingAddresses" basically serving as an alias for "addresses") in order to be able to return both scoped queries at the same time.  It works, but I wanted to see if anybody had any alternatives that didn't involve what feels like a hack.  How else could I do this via Eloquent (I'd find using DB:: even more inelegant than this particular workaround)?

```
    $query = Child::orderBy('last_name')->orderBy('first_name');
    $query->with( 
        array( 
            'family'=>function($query) use($school_year_id) {
                $query->select('families.*')->with( 
                    array(
                        'qualifyingAddresses'=>function($query2) use ($school_year_id){
                            $query2->whereQualifyingFirst($school_year_id)->select('family_addresses.*');
                        },
                        'addresses'=>function($query3) use ($school_year_id){
                            $query3->whereFinal($school_year_id)->select('family_addresses.*');
                        }
                    )
                );
            }
        )
    );
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this personally. What makes you feel like this is incorrect?

Comment: Is eager loading all addresses, then getting the head/tail as needed, too expensive?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it per se, I had just never seen mention of it as a technique.  Honestly, since I'd seen a few related questions I though I'd put this out for critique, and if nobody has a better solution then it'll be available on this site for other folks to poach later.

Comment: As for eager loading everything and then searching through the results, that would be a viable solution as well, but it doesn't let me take advantage of the scoping, which I find useful for code clarity.  Actually, the first "qualifying" address wouldn't necessarily be the head of the list, so I'd have to do evaluation on each returned record until I found it, which the scoped query takes care of up front.

Comment: Yeah sorting them on-the-go is the other option (which one will give better performance depends on a lot of factors). For code clarity you could use accessors. Something like [this (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/wDQi5Tbj).

Comment: Unfortunately, since both runs at Address require a parameter be passed, I don't think the accessor approach is an option.